# rsync command to content inside a zip file without fully extracting the zip

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro

I am using manjaro. Below command i use to backup my whole system.

```
rsync -aAXv --delete --exclude-from="excludefrombackup" / /home/vipin/mydata/backup
```

Above command will copy the my root (/) and backup it to a different location.

The rsync copy all the files and folders exactly the same structure and permissions.

When i execute same command  second time it will modify only the changes done to my system to the backup location. This is working fine.

But now i want to zip my backup, When i do the second time update it should delete from the zip without extracting. Is it possible or Do i need to do like this

1. Extract the zip file
2. Run rsync
3. compress again.

Do anyone having a script for this. I want to achieve this through script.

Comment: It seems like you want to use rsync for something it's not build for. I would recommend looking into real backup tools which supports compression out of the box.

Comment: @mikael kjaer Thanks for the reply. Because of some security restriction i need to right the script for this. is to possible to do rsync or any other command?